# Utilizar input() dentro de un ciclo for (Python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops

Estoy tratando de crear una matriz en la cual sea el usuario quien ingrese el número de filas, columnas y cada término:

```
colum=int(input('Cantidad de columnas: '))
fil=int(input('Cantidad de filas: '))
matriz=[[str(input('[',i,',',j,']-esimo termino: ')) for i in range(colum)] for j in range(fil)]
```

Sin embargo, luego de ingresar el número de filas y de columnas me arroja el error:

> ```
> TypeError: input expected at most 1 arguments, got 5
> ```

He tratado de reescribir el código de distintas formas y me sigue arrojando el mismo error. Mi pregunta es, ¿No puedo colocar un input() dentro de un ciclo for? O en todo caso ¿cual ha sido mi error aquí?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es que estas usando `input` como si le pasaras argumentos a la función `print`. `print` acepta un numero indeterminado de argumentos, `input` solo acepta uno de tipo `str`. La solución es unir tus cadenas para que formar una única cadena, un único argumento. Para formatear el string que le pasas a `input` lo más adecuado es usar el método [`format`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) de las cadenas:

```
colum=int(input('Cantidad de columnas: '))
fil=int(input('Cantidad de filas: '))
matriz=[[str(input('[{},{}]-esimo termino: '.format(i, j))) for i in range(colum)] for j in range(fil)]
```

Con lo que obtenemos:

> Cantidad de columnas: 3
>   Cantidad de filas: 2
>   [0,0]-esimo termino: 1
>   [1,0]-esimo termino: 2
>   [2,0]-esimo termino: 3
>   [0,1]-esimo termino: 4
>   [1,1]-esimo termino: 5
>   [2,1]-esimo termino: 6
>   >>> matriz
>   [['1', '2', '3'], ['4', '5', '6']]

Existe otra forma alternativa que es concatenar cadenas pero la forma recomendada es la anterior, además de ser más simple:

```
matriz=[[str(input('['+str(i)+','+str(j)+'-esimo termino: ')) for i in range(colum)] for j in range(fil)]
```

Comment: No conocía dicho método, muchísimas gracias!